# Sporadic NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED from BackupPC via Samba

Tags: samba, backuppc

I have a BackupPC Server pulling backups from a Gentoo Linux machine (ext3 fs). This fails sporadically throwing errors like this

```
2014-06-10 12:00:19 full backup started for share uni
2014-06-10 12:03:43 Got fatal error during xfer (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \\*)
2014-06-10 12:03:48 Backup aborted (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \\*)
```

into the log.

It is an authority problem: Going to the target base folder and saying something drastic like

```
chmod -R a+r *
```

solves it for some time.

However, the target user in question sometimes creates files which have only read-access for himself (then again, why shouldn't he?).

Naturally it would be okay if such files are excluded from the backup. But here comes the question: Is there any way to rig backuppc such that the error above is turned into a mere warning, not stopping the rest of the backup?

Comment: BackupPC is quite sensitive when it comes to its backup methods. Sure you _could_ stop backing up or continue it regardless of the exit status, but on the other hand, if your task is to backup *everything*, then please do that. You know the users; they suddenly tell you they deleted <something unexpected> and if you was not able to back that up in the first place, you're screwed. Please find out why you was not able to backup those users in the first place, correct that, and let the life go on.